# How to enter a value in Shadow-root (user-agent) Java-Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, shadow-root

I used many options, but not one did not help

[image: The place where you need to enter the value]

Used options:

[image: 1]

Then I tried the same thing, but with a separate method

[image: method]

[image: 2]

option 3

[image: 3]

option 4

[image: 4]

option 5 (this option records the value, but the page does not see it)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmNFL.png)

[image: 5]

Comment: Hey Tenny, welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"xpath")))

elem.send_keys("Text")
```

Comment: Alas, waiting for the element didn't help. The recording goes through as if used without waiting, but then it is quickly deleted